# Extracting data from an unusual JSON

Tags: json, csv, hierarchical-data, jq

Is there a way to make a nice CSV out of the following JSON code?

```
{
    "cod:e1!!@23" : {
        "typeA" : {
            "lsk:d##fjd": {
                "title" : "slkdfjlkdjfd",
                "year" : "2014"
            },
        "sdfdsfsd" : {
            "title" : "slkdfjlkdjfddewfsdfd",
            "year" : "2015"
            }
        },
        "Ct@ype" : {
            "sd$!!fs:$dfds" : {
                "title" : "slkdfjsdfsdfdsfsd",
                "year" : "2012"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what I tried in jq:

```
jq -rc 'keys[] as $x 
  | .[]|keys[] as $y
  | .[]|keys[] as $z
  |.[]
  |[$x,$y,$z,.year] | @csv'

jq -rc 'keys_unsorted[] as $x
  | .[]|keys_unsorted[] as $y
  | .[]|keys_unsorted[] as $z
  | .[]|[$x,$y,$z,.year] | @csv'
```

But the output is not correct, because if there are several such records then  the keys come out as sorted and permuted. I also tried keys_unsorted, but it didn't resolve the issue.

Fixing the original JSON generation is not an option at this point in time, so any help will be appreciated.

Ideally, I would get:

```
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","lsk:d##fjd","slkdfjlkdjfd","2014"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","sdfdsfsd","slkdfjlkdjfddewfsdfd","2015"
"cod:e1!!@23","Ct@ype","sd$!!fs:$dfds","slkdfjsdfsdfdsfsd","2012"
```

Comment: Could you describe what should be the "good" output of your example.

Comment: Thank you, corrected the question!

Comment: The JSON seems to be a bit unusual, but perfectly fine. Nothing "badly-structured".

Comment: Yes, 'unusual' is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small modification to the script you provide in the initial post makes it work. Instead of using .[], I index by the specific key that is saved as variable from `keys_unsorted`. I also added a header to the CSV for convenience:

```
jq -r '["x", "y", "z", "title", "year"],
  (keys_unsorted[] as $x
   | .[$x] | keys_unsorted[] as $y
   | .[$y] | keys_unsorted[] as $z
   | .[$z] | [$x, $y, $z, .title, .year]) | @csv'
```

This does provide the output you're looking for (with a header):

```
"x","y","z","title","year"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","lsk:d##fjd","slkdfjlkdjfd","2014"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","sdfdsfsd","slkdfjlkdjfddewfsdfd","2015"
"cod:e1!!@23","Ct@ype","sd$!!fs:$dfds","slkdfjsdfsdfdsfsd","2012"
```

Comment: I can see now why I was getting all those permutations! Thanks, basically I should've reused the variables, rather than starting a new `[]` branch. :)

Answer (score 1):

The following provides a general solution for regularly structured
nested objects (loosely speaking, they can be thought of "babushka objects", like the nested dolls); furthermore, the keys within objects can be ordered in any way.

The key concept is that of "scalar objects" -- objects all of whose
keys have scalar values.

A template for the information to be extracted from the "scalar
objects" is provided as a parameter to the 'emit' filter and is used
to ensure that the appropriate order is maintained when producing
the CSV lines.

```
def emit(template):

  def is_scalar_object:
    def is_scalar: type | ((. != "object") and (. != "array"));
    . as $in | (type == "object") and all($in[] | is_scalar);

  . as $in
  | paths as $path
  | select(getpath($path) | is_scalar_object)
  | $path + [ template + ($in | getpath($path)) | .[]]
  ;


data | emit( {title,  year} ) | @csv
```

Usage:

```
 jq -r emit.jq input.json
```

Output:

```
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","lsk:d##fjd","slkdfjlkdjfd","2014"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","sdfdsfsd","slkdfjlkdjfddewfsdfd","2015"
"cod:e1!!@23","Ct@ype","sd$!!fs:$dfds","slkdfjsdfsdfdsfsd","2012"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I already accepted an answer, and hesitate changing it, but of course your answer is more general. This will be handy in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'https://github.com/zemirco/json2csv' with the `flatten` option. This will generate columns like `cod:e1!!@23.typeA.lsk:d##fjd.title`.

```
cat input.json | json2csv -F >> output.csv
```

**EDIT**: This is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for json2csv reference, the output is not what I'm looking for, but the program might be handy in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jq script that traverses the "leaf elements" in the input and makes a CSV column out of every key it goes through:

```
jq -r 'leaf_paths as $path | $path + [getpath($path)] | @csv'
```

Note that this is not exactly what you're looking for:

```
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","lsk:d##fjd","title","slkdfjlkdjfd"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","lsk:d##fjd","year","2014"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","sdfdsfsd","title","slkdfjlkdjfddewfsdfd"
"cod:e1!!@23","typeA","sdfdsfsd","year","2015"
"cod:e1!!@23","Ct@ype","sd$!!fs:$dfds","title","slkdfjsdfsdfdsfsd"
"cod:e1!!@23","Ct@ype","sd$!!fs:$dfds","year","2012"
```

Comment: As you write, it's a bit different from what I want, but very workable.